# strange issue with auto number field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have created a table which has auto increment field. I inserted a few records and deleted them. We had to change the php.ini file and restarted the machine. The auto increment field started from 1 again. I have a web site which uses Joomla running on windows server 2008. It looks like PHP and MySQL are integrated with Joomla. I am new to PHP and MySQL server. Please let me know what could be the issue? I am running PHP 5.3.8 and MySQL server 5.0. Thank you for any help.

Comment: This shouldn't normally happen: Used auto-increment IDs will never be re-used. Are you sure the plugin didn't auto-recreate the field or something? Are you sure you inserted the data in the same table?

Comment: how did you delete, with truncate (empty in phpmyadmin) or delete? .. truncate will reset the auto incrementer

Comment: The only way auto_increment could have been reset to 1 is if the table was dropped and re-created, or an alter was run against it to reset the auto_increment value. What did you change in the php.ini file?

Comment: @Pekka "Used auto-increment IDs will never be re-used."?  What about after 4 billion rows have been added and deleted?

Comment: I double checked the data. I am sure I have inserted in the same table. If I leave the table data, then it works as expected. I created a new table with AutoIncrement.

Comment: @Fantius good question, I have no idea what mySQL will do then :) but my suspicion would be that it simply won't add any new records to the table

Comment: I changed the display_errors = On to off.

Comment: I deleted using the delete from table command.

Comment: @nav100: What did you do to your php.ini file? Still trying to figure out how that is relevant to your issue. When you "initialized" joomla, did you run some sort of bootstrap script? Chances are there may have been a drop table command, during a schema rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the TRUNCATE or DELETE command to delete the data?
If it is TRUNCATE it will reset the auto increment value.

Answer (score 1):

That should not happen normaly . But as an remedy you could use the following query to reset 
the auto increment counter to the previously last value .

```
ALTER TABLE theTableInQuestion AUTO_INCREMENT=newalue , so that you could continue with t
```

able as usual by setting newvalue = last autoincrementvalue +1